# How to gevent.sleep in current gevent.pool

Tags: python, gevent, eventlet, greenlets

Lets say I have two gevent pool groups

```
gevent_pool_1 = Pool(2)
gevent_pool_2 = Pool(2)
```

I want to

```
gevent.sleep(10)
```

in

```
gevent_pool_1
```

which will not block the

```
gevent_pool_2
```

Comment: You can make a Greenlet within a Pool sleeping but not the Pool itself.

Comment: thanks for the answer, just wondered why isn't it supporting?
It could be useful on per session rate-limiting or something like that...